# WebApp Downgrade to D1 Remove SSL

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have WebApp currently host as B1, and would like to downgrade to D1.
as D1, it not allow SSL.

```
Cannot update the site with hostname 'www.domain.com' because its current SSL configuration 'SNI enabled' is not allowed in the target compute mode. Allowed SSL configuration is 'Disabled'.
```

How to perform this downgrade step, is fine with me to remove temporary the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To downgrade to D1, you need to remove the SSL Binding first.

Navigate to the `TLS/SSL settings` of your web app in the portal -> click the `Delete` like below.

[image]

After removing the binding, you will be able to downgrade the web app to D1, if you also want to remove the certificate, navigate to the `Private Key Certificates (.pfx)` to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And if it still doesn't work because it says there is a hostname that uses that certificate you have to go thru all your other web apps and remove the bindings there before you can delete the certificate for this app and then finally downgrade.